# UISplitViewController from XCode 6 template smaller size in iPhone 5 iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, size-classes

I am building an Universal app with Multiple Detail View with UISplitViewController storyboard based version. iOS 8 works perfectly on all types of devices. It also works fine with some tweaks for iOS 7, but when I run it on iPhone 5 or 5s simulator the view is shrinked; it is equal to the size of iPhone 4s. I tried disabling size classes for iPhone but didn't change nothing.

I have no idea why it happens. There are some other questions here that suggest to turn off size classes but they do not solve my problem.

[image]

Comment: Do you have launch images of the correct size for iPhone 5? Last time I saw this, that was the issue.

Comment: no but hell I experienced another time this issue now that I remember

Comment: Have you tried: Delete app in simulator, quit simulator, build clean, build and run.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel Adding launch image solved the issue thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this could be because you have not provided a launch image of the correct dimensions for iPhone 5.

This should correct the problem